# Объединение файлов в форму

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

Иногда бывает надо пересоздать проект. А исходники копируешь (частично) из старого. Так вот и есть допустим формы разные (UserControl, Window...). Они соответственно как обычно состоят из .xaml и .xaml.cs файлов. Я добавляю их в проект, но они отображаются как разрозненные файлы. Они не как одна форма. Как сделать чтобы как вот они добавляются по умолчанию при создании одной формой были? Вот скрин: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zt1ph8fwl1vn3v5/screen.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

В файле проекта csproj:

```
<Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Page>
<Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Да вроде просто надо добавить в проект файл xaml, а студия автоматом подтянет xaml.cs. Ну, само собой, оба файла должны находиться рядом.